# Subtract grouped figures in Oracle select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an interest table with interest indicator as either Credit or Debit. The requirement is to get the Difference between the Credit and Debit Interest grouping by the Branch. My separated queries are:

```
select sol_id, sum(AMOUNT_IN_LCY)DEBIT_INTEREST from INTEREST_DETAILS where INT_ID = 'D' group by sol_id;
```

My other query is:

```
select sol_id, sum(AMOUNT_IN_LCY)CREDIT_INTEREST from INTEREST_DETAILS where INT_ID = 'C' group by sol_id;
```

I am totally Stuck on adding or subtracting the two queries into One resultSet grouped by sol_id. Any ideas?? Is there a way to subtract the figures first and then group them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sol_id, (sum(CASE WHEN INT_ID = 'C' THEN AMOUNT_IN_LCY ELSE 0 END)-
sum(CASE WHEN INT_ID = 'D' THEN AMOUNT_IN_LCY ELSE 0 END)) as Difference 
from INTEREST_DETAILS  
group by sol_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select sol_id, ABS(sum(DECODE(INT_ID, 'D', -1, 1) * AMOUNT_IN_LCY)) DIFFERENCE 
  from INTEREST_DETAILS
 group by sol_id
```

It will give you the difference in positive between debit and credit for each `sol_id`.

Comment: What is Subtracted from what is this debit Subtracted from credit or the other way round?

Comment: This way debit is substracted from credit. If you need it the other way around you only have to change the signs of the factors. Is this what you asked for?

Comment: Yes definitely but My confusion is why there is a -(minus) symbol before each figure which is incorrect when I subtract the debit from the credit?

Comment: By figure I understand you mean the result of the difference, correct? If that is the case then you have more `debit` than `credit` in some cases. I can not tell yoy why as I have no access to your data. Anyway, what `DECODE` does is the same as an `if` sentence like this `if INT_ID = 'D' then return -1 else return 1`. Multiplying its result with `AMOUNT_IN_LCY` converts `debit` to negative values and `credit` to positive (assuming all were positive from the beginning). Then `SUM` sums all the values for each `sol_id` and that gives you the difference.

Comment: My debit is more than the credit in all the branches. So I expected the Figure to be a Positive figure when subtracted from the credit.

Comment: Ok, but if `credit < debit` always then the difference `credit - debit` would always be negative. Anyway, you can use the `ABS` function to make the result positive (I'll edit the answer to show how) or use @Mihai's approach.

Comment: Ok Any Idea how I can add Up a sum from another table like I have asked in My follow up question Here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296183/add-amounts-from-two-different-tables-oracle

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.sol_id,
sum(t1.DEBIT_INTEREST)DEBIT_INTEREST,sum(t1.CREDIT_INTEREST)CREDIT_INTEREST
FROM
(select sol_id, 
case when INT_ID = 'D' then AMOUNT_IN_LCY else 0 end DEBIT_INTEREST,
case when INT_ID = 'C' then AMOUNT_IN_LCY else 0 end CREDIT_INTEREST
from INTEREST_DETAILS)t1  group by t1.sol_id;
```